# How to re-run a Netlogo run?

Tags: netlogo

Is there any way to re-run a Netlogo model exactly as before? (i.e. effectively press Go again and have the run be exactly the same as the last one.)

As I understand it, all you would need to be able to do this is to find out the random seed that was used in the last run - can this be done? Then all you would need to do is include the code "random-seed xxx" in the setup.

This feature would be really useful, so if it can't be done, maybe it could be implemented in future versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming here you still want each run of your model to be different (change the random seed each time).  According to the [NetLogo Programming Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random):

> If you don't set the random seed yourself, NetLogo sets it to a value based on the current date and time. There is no way to find out what random seed it chose, so if you want your model run to be reproducible, you must set the random seed yourself ahead of time.

So we can do this, we just need to handle "remembering" the random seed ourselves.  Assuming you've got a standard `setup` procedure that has to be executed before the model runs:

```
globals [ run-seed ]

to setup
  set run-seed new-seed ; get a random seed to use for our run
  random-seed run-seed
  ; do the rest of our normal setup
end
```

Now when your model run is done you can `show run-seed` in the command center, or print it out in code to record it.  Then you can use that seed instead of the `new-seed` in the `setup` procedure to reproduce the model run exactly in the future.

Comment: Thank you for this, the quotation from the programming guide explains it. What you suggest is useful, but if something interesting emerges from a model every 100 runs, it would be good if you could grab the random seed Netlogo generated and plug that into setup in order to re-create the interesting run. There are people from the development team who look at these - do you think that could be added to a future version?

Comment: I think what I posted should work for what you're asking - you can "save" the `our-seed` every run and plug it right back in to get the same run.  We're just using `our-seed` instead of the NetLogo seed.  I do absolutely agree that it'd be helpful to be able to do this for any model, not just the ones that we can edit to have this functionality.

Comment: OK I looked a bit closer. What you suggest works fine. Bit of a fuss is all. Thanks!

Comment: The `new-seed` primitive may be useful here as well.